# task based language alternative to Makefile

Tags: bash, programming-languages, makefile

In `Makefile`'s I can define tasks so that a user can specify what s/he wants to do as:

```
make run
make serve
make deploy
..
```

This seems to be working ok but I feel like `Makefile`'s are an overkill for this purpose with all those dependency analysis and relatively obscure syntax/execution. Are there any language/tool that is specifically designed for this purpose preferably available on most systems? or any idea how to use something like `bash` for this purpose?

Comment: If you don't want dependency analysis, maybe all you really need is a `switch` statement in the language of your choice.

Comment: Have you considered just creating an executable bash file for each of those commands? Then your user could just type `run` `serve` `deploy`  etc. You can use the `source` built-in to import library functions, settings, configuration, etc. from other files.

Comment: Do you compile a source code? If yes, I think the dependency-analysis isn't unnecessary.

Comment: @ArjunShankar I have come up with a solution, thanks for the suggestion. @rici Arjin's idea seems much cleaner. @uzsolt I'm not going to compile code with this script or maybe I can call `make` from the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after Arjun's suggestion, I have come up with a `sh` script:

```
#!/usr/bin sh

# only one task at a time
if [ $# != 1 ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 <task_name>"
fi

run() {
    echo "I'm now running"
}

serve() {
    echo "I'm now serving"
}

deploy() {
    echo "I'm now deploying"
}

case $1 in
    "run")        run;;
    "serve")      serve;;
    "deploy")     deploy;;
esac
```

which was a lot easier than I imagined. I have named the file `task` so that I can now run the tasks as:

```
$ sh task serve
I'm now serving
```

or if the file is executable:

```
$ ./task deploy
I'm now deploying
```

There's just a little bit duplication in `switch` statement but it's good enough for me. Feel free to drop me a comment if it can get any better.

Comment: Looks a hell of a lot like an initscript (i.e. `/etc/init.d/*` or `/etc/rc.d/*`). If you want suggestions in style, maybe you could peek at one of those files ;)

Comment: Reinventing the wheel now and then isn't an entirely bad thing. It deepens your understanding of wheels.

Comment: Note that there are advantages/differences/disadvantages in using Make for targets as functions, as compared to writing Bash functions for the task. Specifically, Make provides a macro/templating/text substitution language on top of the Bash commands in the target. This provides much flexibility/power, and the ability to solve most code duplication issues. However, it's not clear to me yet if the added flexibility is a good thing w.r.t. code readability down the road.